# how to get integer value from string using preg_match php

Tags: php, preg-match

I want to find integer value using [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) (PHP) from following string value. I am using following code to find integer value, it works fine for positive integer but I need for positive and negative both. Can anyone help me??

String Value: Hint: **Status: -1** Response: Goodbye Message: Thanks for all the fish.

preg_match code so far:

```
preg_match('/Status: (\d+)/', $queueinfo, $status1 );
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is almost there:

```
preg_match('/Status: (\d+)/', $queueinfo, $status1 );
```

The only thing you need to add is the optional dash prefix:

```
preg_match('/Status: (-?\d+)/', $queueinfo, $status1 );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$queueinfo  = 'Hint: Status: -1 Response: Goodbye Message: Thanks for all the fish.';
preg_match('/Status:\s*(?P<status>\-?\d+)/', $queueinfo, $match );  

echo $match['status'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try:

```
preg_match('/Status\:\s(\-?)(\d+)/', $queueinfo, $m);
$status1 = (int)($m[1].$m[2]);
```

Comment: Why not just do `/Status: (-?\d+)/` and then `$m[1]` no need to typecast as well since it is a numeric string otherwise regex would not have matched it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
preg_match_all('/-\d+|(?!-)\d+/', 'String Value: Hint: Status: -1 Response: 12588 Goodbye Message: Thanks for all the fish.', $status1 );
print_r($status1);
?>
```

Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => -1 [1] => 12588 ) )